# kivy gui does not start

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am writing the code for my first app. But the Kivy GUI does not start on my pc. Do you know what the problem could be? Now, you can also find the error message below.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cls = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="U G"))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline= False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="hbh"))
        self.namee = TextInput(multiline= False)
        self.add_widget(self.namee)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

TestApp().run()
```

Here is the error:

```py
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 938, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 815, in kivy.properties.ObservableList.__init__
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ? If yes, include that in your post.

Comment: Ok, here is a correction: The app does start but it immediately quits after one second.

Comment: @ApuCoder yes, now you can see it.

Comment: Did you mean `self.cols = 2` instead of `self.cls = 2` ?

Comment: @ApuCoder Oooh!